# How environmental factors affect aerosol transmission?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

I am totally an amateur in this field, but I need this for my own multi-disciplinary project.

I know this might be a basic question, and I actually did do some researches. I just want to make sure that my understandings are correct. And I also have some questions.

---

My goal:

I want to calculate how far can aerosols diffuse/transmit in some public area.

---

My understandings:

- According to [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0004698174900456), size of the aerosol particles is
  related to relative humidity.
- According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerosol#Dynamics), we can thus describe the diffusion of aerosol population.
- [This article](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/5.0022859) studies the transmission of droplets (0μm ~ 100μm, which includes aerosols), and it says temperature has little effect on the transmission. And it mentions humidity in introduction but it doesn't mention humidity in conclusion, so I guess the authors mean that humidity does not matter? According to the authors, air flow velocity/size of the particles are the majors factor influncing how far could aerosols travel.

> We have also studied the impact of the temperature on the space–time evolution of the trajectories exploring a wide range from 0 °C to 40 °C, and the results show a limited impact, that is, of about 10%.

---

Question:

If the article mentioned in the third bulletpoint is correct, which means that faster air flow velocity means further transmission, why should we keep windows open during the pandemic? Is it because of the lower density of aerosols within the whole area? How can we calculate/estimate such thing using the equations in wikipedia?

Comment: Windows must be kept open to flush out the contaminated air inside a room. Calculating it is a full-fledged research problem that cannot possibly be answered here.

Comment: @Deep That is correct, thank you for your comment. Well, that is only my side-thoughts though. And so, am I understanding other things correctly?

Comment: Humidity matters in that it determines the evaporation rate of airborne droplets. Other than that I think you have got everything else correct.

Comment: As Deep already mentioned, these questions are studies that you cannot easily calculate. There are many parameters into account. You can perform a back-of-the-envelope calculation and get an answer. that is no way representative for the real world, because of the assumptions.